# set new entity property to property of existing entity in ObjectContext

Tags: linq, entity-framework, objectcontext

I've created a new Entity Object:

```
 mplToCreate = this._context.MasterPartsList.CreateOBject();
```

then, I want to set the `parentPnID` to an existing item's property that I tried querying for using the following `IQueryable` expression:

```
mplToCreate.parentPnID = this._context.MasterPartNumbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.pn == this._selectedItem.Pn).pnID;
```

But I get a `NullReferenceException` at that line. (I know that there exists a `pnID` in `MasterPartNumbers` that matches this logic.)

Please help me correct my right-hand expression so that I can set the property accordingly.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus  See latest comment below Nicholas Butler's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a typo, or is it the problem?

```
// assignment
FirstOrDefault(x => x.pn = this._selectedItem.Pn)

// equality
FirstOrDefault(x => x.pn == this._selectedItem.Pn)
```

Comment: Oops! Sorry @NicholasButler, that was just a typo. It's correct in my application.

Comment: No problem. Your code looks correct - I would guess the problem is in your data. Which part of the expression is null?

Comment: Ah. I'm tired. I just realized the SelectedItem is currently null in from inside my SaveEntities RelayCommand (they look like Josh Smith's). How should I pass the current property value of this to my RelayCommand? Would you happen to know? Thanks for your help. I'm pretty sure that will solve my problem. I'll start a new Q for that just in case.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks anyway!